# Cannot get duration in FFmpeg laravel

Tags: laravel, video, ffmpeg, duration

i follow the command in the github and find alot of reference, but it return a large object, and cannot access the duration

here is my code

```
  $ffprobe = \FFMpeg\FFProbe::create();
  $ffprobe
      ->format($file) // extracts file informations
      ->get('duration');             // returns the duration property

  dd($ffprobe);
```

[image]

if i use Echo or Return it will give me error

```
Object of class FFMpeg\FFProbe could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you're trying to echo the instance of FFProb not the duration. how about this:

```
$duration = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create()
        ->format($file)
        ->get('duration');

echo $duration;
```